# How to change a special character in a csv file before uploading into a dataframe in python with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

So I have a large data set where the strings are surrounded with " symbols but in some cases they have been replaced with ” symbols, the issue with that is, it's causing pandas to think my separators are part of the elements therefore joining to elements together.

I'm hoping to find a way to replace the ” symbol with " without fixing up the csv file since the code will be used by someone who will most likely have a version of the dataset with those special characters and won't be fixing it up.

The dataset is quite large (21 columns, over 4000 rows) but here is a small example with the issue:

```
"a";"b";"c";"d";"e";"f"
30;"yes";4.4;"Monday";"no";"yes"
39;"no";3.4;"Tuesday";"no";"no"
47;"no";2.1;"Tuesday”;”no";"yes”
25;"yes";4.5;"wednesday";"no";"yes"
```

Below is the code I've been trying to use but I can't seem to get that to work:

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO
dataset = 'datafile.csv'
sio = StringIO(dataset)
v = sio.getvalue()
v = v.replace('”',"",)
sio.write(dataset)
df = pd.read_csv(dataset, sep=';', decimal='.', skiprows = 1, header= None, names=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'])
```

Comment: should it be `v.replace('”','"')` ?

Comment: Have you checked with encoding ?

Comment: I'm a little puzzled as to why you just don't make a copy of the file, use a regex to alter it as needed, and then import it into pandas. Also, the sample "with the issue" has been stripped of the characters you've indicated to be problematic.

Comment: @tdelaney Just using the code `v.replace('”','"',)` doesn't seem to make a difference i seem to get an output of `'datafile.csv'` when I do. @Harry_pb I haven't checked with that so I'll look into that. @chb Ah, I didn't know that was a possibility (I'm pretty new to python and pandas) so I'll try that. The ” characters are in there it's on the 4th row between Tuesday and no `"Tuesday”;”no"`

Comment: my bad, `v.replace` returns the new string and that's what you put into the StringIO buffer. I'll share an answer.

Comment: Also, this is python 2 but you've got that non-ascii quote? The file read should fail, shouldn't it?

Comment: okay, me again... you were processing the string "datafile.csv" not the actual file. This should have really ended badly.

Comment: @tdelaney ahhhh ok, so I should be changing `sio = StringIO(dataset)` to `sio=StringIO(datafile.csv)`. Also it's python 2.7

Comment: Is python 3 available to you? Its unicode support is better. I'll try to get a 2.7 example going. But 3 has been out a decade now... could be time to switch.

Comment: "dataset is quite large (21 columns, over 4000 rows)" this is not large!

Comment: @tdelaney Yeah it seems like I could have avoided this mess to begin with right from the start by using 3 but your solution works perfectly for me! Thanks heaps!

Comment: @AndyHayden I kind of meant it was too large to display here but the thought of there being larger data sets out there makes my legs a little weak haha!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str.replace` returns the updated string. You should wrap that in a `StringIO` and then pass it to `pandas`. Your code appears to be python 2, but python 3 is much better at unicode issues. Here is a python 3 solution that works on the example data set:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

dataset = 'datafile.csv'
sio = StringIO(open(dataset).read().replace('”','"'))
df = pd.read_csv(sio, sep=';', decimal='.', skiprows = 1, header= None, names=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'])
print(df)
```

Here is a solution that works for python 2.7. I am assuming that the CSV file is UTF-8 encoded and that you are using a UTF-8 enabled editor to write the python script. That's normal for unixy systems but may be problematic on windows.

```
# coding=utf-8

import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO
import codecs

dataset = 'datafile.csv'
sio = StringIO(codecs.open(dataset, encoding="utf-8").read().replace(u'”',u'"'))
df = pd.read_csv(sio, sep=';', decimal='.', skiprows = 1, header= None, names=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'])
print(df)
```

Comment: The main (?) issue being that OP's code `sio = StringIO('datafile.csv')` didn't read the file. :)

Comment: The solution did manage to work for me in python 2 so that's pretty neat thanks for solving my problem! Thanks! But I'll definitely look into python 3 so I can avoid these problems from the start!